# Can't download a PDF file within FirefoxOS webapp

Tags: pdf, web-applications, firefox-os, pdf.js

I'm trying to download a PDF file from a Firefox OS webapp, but when I try to do it PDF.js gives me the following error:

```
PDF.js v0.8.997 (compilacion: 3fa15c8)
Mensaje: Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "http://xxxx.xx/xxx.pdf"
```

This occurs when I'm debbuging through "WebIDE" extension in Firefox. When I try to do the same whith an FirefoxOS emulator, I can download the file, but it is not stored. In fact, when I press on the notification I receive a message telling me that the file cannot be founded.

When I do the same on the browsers (Firefox, Chrome, ...) I don't have the same error, so I think that I cant discard HTTP headers problems.

I'm not sure, but... Can be this an issue related with the fact that it's an untrusted webapp?

UPDATE:

I tried to do the same but with a jpeg file and I didn't have any problems. This makes my think that it's a PDF.js issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla's [pdfjs](/questions/tagged/pdfjs) uses an XMLHttpRequest (`XHR`) to request the pdf-file. Check out their [network code](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/network.js), especially [Line 101](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/network.js#L101). Your application needs the `systemXHR` permission, in order to use XHR.

> **SystemXHR**
>
> Allows anonymous (no cookies) cross-origin XHR without the
>   target site having CORS enabled. Similar to the TCP Socket API but
>   restricted to XHR, not just raw sockets, so it is slightly less risky.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions

Do not forget, to change your application type to `privileged` in your `manifest.webapp`:

```
"name": "app",
"description": "My description",
"type": "privileged",
"permissions": {
  "systemXHR": {
    "description": "Add a description for the marketplace reviewer"
  }
}
```

Please notice, that Firefox OS aims to be run on devices with low memory. You should consider to save the PDF file to the [device-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API) (sdcard) first, before opening it.

Comment: I think that it's a good point @mate64. It's so good... that I have tried it already :) But this theory doesn't explain why when I access directly to the file through the app, without the processing that I need to do, I can download and see the file, but when I process it I get the error that I explain in the question.

This make me think that it's a issue related with HTTP headers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What are the response headers of the xhr request?

Comment: It's another problem... When I connect the device with the WebIDE the Newtwork tab disappear so I can't see any headers (neither request headers neither response headers). When I debug with the FirefoxOS simulator I have no problems to download the file, but it isn't saved on the device (as expected because it's a hosted app and I don't have any write permissions on the device?)
Anyway I tried with the same headers that appears when I download directly the file, and I have no more success. It's a bit strange all.